# How to change attributes in __init__ with a method in the same class?

Tags: python

I have a method that is supposed to calculate the final price of gas, but the attribute in `__init__` is already set to 0 and won't change.

I expected the final price to be 60, but the final price was 0 which was what I set in `__init__`

```
class Normal:
    def __init__(self,gp,g):
        self.gas_price = gp
        self.gallons = g
        self.final_price = 0
    def calc_price(self):
        self.final_price = self.gas_price * self.gallons
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Normal gas price: {self.gas_price}. Gallons filled: {self.gallons}. Final price: {self.final_price}."
    

c1 = Normal(4,15)
print(c1)
```

Comment: You never call `calc_price` anywhere.

Comment: Why not put `self.final_price = self.gas_price * self.gallons` in `__init__` and omit intialising to 0?

Comment: @user19077881 Because that wouldn't be DRY.

Comment: Replace `self.final_price = 0` with `self.calc_price()`

Comment: Another option would be to make `final_price` a property that performs the calculation whenever you read it, instead of storing it.

Comment: A third option would be to call `self.calc_price()` in the `__str__` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the `calc_price()` method is not being called so the code in that method is never run and final_price will remain at 0. There are various fixes to this. You can simply call the function after instantiating the class like this

```
c1 = Normal(4, 15)
c1.calc_price()
print(c1)
```

or if you want this to be done automatically when instantiating the class you could call the function from your `__init__` method like this

```
class Normal:
    def __init__(self, gp, g):
        self.gas_price = gp
        self.gallons = g
        self.final_price = 0
        self.calc_price()

    def calc_price(self):
        self.final_price = self.gas_price * self.gallons

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Normal gas price: {self.gas_price}. Gallons filled: {self.gallons}. Final price: {self.final_price}."
```

Answer (score 0):

- you should really make the calc_price method private if you call it in the **init**, with a dunder
- besides the checking you should do when two floats are ofered to a method, and the proper cammel casing
- you then need to call self.__calc_price and rename parameters ike so

---

```
class Normal:
    def __init__(self,gp,g):
        self.gas_price = gp
        self.gallons = g
        self.__ThisIsTheFiguerZero = 0
        self.__final_price = self.__calc_price(gp,g)
    def __calc_price(self):
        self.final_price = self.gas_price *   self.gallons
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Normal gas price: {self.gas_price}. Gallons filled: {self.gallons}. Final price: {self.final_price}."


$ c1 = Normal(4,15)
$ print(c1)
```

Comment: What is the point of `self.__final_price = self.__calc_price(gp,g)` in `__init__`? What is the point of `self.__ThisIsTheFiguerZero = 0`? What cammel\* casing are you talking about? There's no private in python.